# numpy: get the ndarray dtype from recarray dtype

Tags: numpy

I have a recarray returned by a function, I want to turn it into an ndarray with the same dtype. An example is the the `z` variable in the following code. How can I get `d1` from the `dtype` of `z`?

```
>>> d1 = np.dtype([('a', float), ('b', int)])
>>> x = np.random.randn(4).view(d1); x
array([( 1.3209, -1.11  ), (-1.1721, -0.5442)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])

>>> y = x.view(np.recarray); y
rec.array([( 1.3209, -1.11  ), (-1.1721, -0.5442)], 
          dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])

>>> z = y.view(np.ndarray); z
array([( 1.3209, -1.11  ), (-1.1721, -0.5442)],
      dtype=(numpy.record, [('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')]))
```

Now you see `z` and `x` have the same data structure but with a different `dtype`. `z.dtype` has a wrapper `np.record` around the `x.dtype`. How can I remove the wrapper to get the underlying `d1`?

Comment: Your `d1` has an `int` field, but all the array have a `f8` for that field.  Was that intentional?  Do you want mixed dtypes or same?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the difference between `y`, the `recarray` and `x` the `structured` array.  They are essentially the same.  A `recarray` just lets you access fields as attributes, e.g. `y.a` works as does `y['a']`, and `x['a']`, but `x.a` does not.

Comment: `x.dtype.descr` and `y.dtype.descr` produce the same thing.  `np.dtype(y.dtype.descr)` returns a dtype without the `record`.  `np.record` is just a subclass of `np.void`.

Comment: Thanks, the change from int to `f8` is just for illustration what can be done for coercing arrays. As long as the dtype is consistent, then we can view it as other dtypes. I think your `np.dtype(y.dtype.descr)` serves as the answer. Do you mind to turn it into an answer? I will then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [19]: d1 = np.dtype([('a',float),('b',float)])
```

A structured array

```
In [20]: x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], d1)                                  
In [21]: x                                                                      
Out[21]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

A recarray view:

```
In [22]: y = x.view(np.recarray)                                                
In [23]: y                                                                      
Out[23]: 
rec.array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)],
          dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

The `dtype`:

```
In [24]: x.dtype                                                                
Out[24]: dtype([('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [25]: y.dtype                                                                
Out[25]: dtype((numpy.record, [('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')]))
```

`dtype` `descr` match, so we can do:

```
In [26]: y.dtype.descr                                                          
Out[26]: [('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')]
In [27]: np.dtype(y.dtype.descr)                                                
Out[27]: dtype([('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [28]: x.dtype                                                                
Out[28]: dtype([('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#record-arrays

> For convenience, viewing an ndarray as type np.recarray will automatically convert to np.record datatype, so the dtype can be left out of the view:
>
> To get back to a plain ndarray both the dtype and type must be reset. The following view does so, taking into account the unusual case that the recordarr was not a structured type:

```
In [31]: y.view(y.dtype.fields, np.ndarray)                                     
Out[31]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

===

With changes in how multifield access is done, `recfunctions` as added some utility functions.  One converts structured to unstructured (which in the past has always been a bit awkward):

```
In [35]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                    
In [36]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(x)                                       
Out[36]: 
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.],
       [5., 6.]])
In [37]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(y)                                       
Out[37]: 
rec.array([[1., 2.],
           [3., 4.],
           [5., 6.]],
          dtype=float64)
In [38]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(y).view(np.ndarray)                      
Out[38]: 
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.],
       [5., 6.]])
```

and the other direction:

```
In [39]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(Out[36], x.dtype)                        
Out[39]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```